# three js mirror not reflecting all meshes

Tags: reflection, three.js

**Objective**:

- To simulate a reflective floor([like this](http://www.lastonepoets.com/gallery/thumbs/lrg-89-cook_crema_marfil_marble_floorrestoration_008.jpg)) in three js.

**Idea**:

- Make the floor translucent by setting opacity to 0.5.
- Place a Mirror below it to reflect the meshes above it.

**Expected Output**:

- To be able to see reflections of the house via the floor mirror.

**Obtained Output**:

- Doesn't reflect the meshes which is part of the house.
- Instead, reflects only the skybox and that too only in certain angles.

*Screenshots*:

- Mirror reflecting skybox fully - http://prntscr.com/6yn52y
- Mirror reflecting skybox partially - http://prntscr.com/6yn5f7
- Mirror not reflecting anything - http://prntscr.com/6yn5qy

**Questions**:

- Why aren't the other meshes of the house reflected through the mirror?
- Why is the mirror not reflecting in certain orientations of the camera?

**Code Attached**:

```
.......
.......
function getReflectiveFloorMesh(floorMesh) {

        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

        floorMirror = new THREE.Mirror( renderer, firstPerson.camera,
                    { clipBias: 0.003,
                    textureWidth: WIDTH,
                    textureHeight: HEIGHT,
                    color: 0x889999 } );

        var mirrorMesh = floorMesh.clone();

        mirrorMesh.position.y -= 10;            // Placing the mirror just below the actual translucent floor; Fixme: To be tuned
        mirrorMesh.material = floorMirror.material;

        mirrorMesh.material.side = THREE.BackSide;  // Fixme: Normals were flipped. How to decide on normals?
        mirrorMesh.material.needsUpdate = true;

        mirrorMesh.add(floorMirror);

        return mirrorMesh;

    }

    function getSkybox() {
        var urlPrefix = "/img/skybox/sunset/";
        var urls = [urlPrefix + "px.png", urlPrefix + "nx.png",
            urlPrefix + "py.png", urlPrefix + "ny.png",
            urlPrefix + "pz.png", urlPrefix + "nz.png"];
        var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);

        // init the cube shadder
        var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["cube"];
        shader.uniforms["tCube"].value = textureCube;
        var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
            vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
            uniforms: shader.uniforms,
            side: THREE.BackSide
        });

        // build the skybox Mesh
        var skyboxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(10000, 10000, 10000, 1, 1, 1, null, true), material);

        return skyboxMesh;
    }

    function setupScene(model, floor) {
        scene.add(model); // Adding the house which contains translucent floor
        scene.add(getSkybox()); // Adding Skybox
        scene.add(getReflectiveFloorMesh(floor)); // Adds mirror just below floor

        scope.animate();
    }
....
....
this.animate = function () {

    // Render the mirrors
    if(floorMirror)
        floorMirror.render();

    renderer.render(scene, firstPerson.camera);
};
```

Comment: clipBias: 0.003 change this to larger?

Comment: mirrorMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2; // or x, y

Comment: Yes. Modifying **clipBias** does impact output to not just reflect the skybox.
[clipbias:3 screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6ynq9x).
It vaguely reflects other meshes as well. Need to **tune** clipBias I guess.

But it still **doesn't** explain why mirror doesn't show reflection in certain angles. [2](http://prntscr.com/6ynql1) , [3](http://prntscr.com/6ynqy6)

Comment: if you had a link i could look, im online for a while

Comment: mirrorMesh.position.y -= 10; if you lift this higher does it reflect properly?, say: mirrorMesh.position.y = 15

Comment: I tried `mirrorMesh.position.y += 5;` i.e above the translucent floor and I observe the same behaviour.
Screenshots : [1](http://prntscr.com/6yo5si) , [2](http://prntscr.com/6yo5zg)
Change in angle affects the output drastically.

Comment: you using http://threejs.org/examples/js/Mirror.js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76335/discussion-between-careen-and-prahadeesh).

Comment: Could you not just use [THREE.CubeCamera](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/CubeCamera)? Example [here](http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/58910953451/dynamic-reflections-in-three-js)

Comment: Not using CubeCamera for reasons mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3261).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach the mirror to the mesh **before** doing any transformation.
So the code would be:

```
floorMirror = new THREE.Mirror( ... );

var mirrorMesh = floorMesh.clone();

    mirrorMesh.add(floorMirror); // attach first!
    mirrorMesh.position.y -= 10; 
    ...
```

But another problem here is that you are cloning `mirrorMesh` from `floorMesh`, which has already been (probably) transformed.

At creation, a mirror object has the same default transform matrix as a regular Mesh with plane geometry (which is by default 'vertical').

When you attach the mirror to a floor (or any horizontal mesh), the matrix doesn't match with the mesh one and that's why you don't see the reflections, or only from a certain angle.

So, always attach a mirror to a **non-transformed plane mesh**, before you apply your transformations (translations or rotations).

Comment: Also, the 'mirror' object supports the use of shaders in materials, so you could write your own shader and mix the floor texture with the reflection texture, like in this example: http://slayvin.net/webgl/camaro/ .


Then you would not need to 'cheat' with two meshes.

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

"*Make the floor translucent by setting opacity to 0.5.
Place a Mirror below it to reflect the meshes above it*".

I suggest another way, make floor as solid add mirror on top and change the alpha of the mirror instead, I think you have issues with the translucent floor restricting the mirror projection through the alpha..

If you move the mirror over from under the translucent floor or into an empty scene with just a cube or sphere geometry attached basic material does it reflect as expected?

You may need 2 mirrors, one for the room assuming you want polished floor boards and one for outside general reflection

Comment: *If you move the mirror over from under the translucent floor or into an empty scene with just a cube or sphere geometry attached basic material does it reflect as expected?*

- Nope. The reflection output varies with orientation of camera as seen [here](http://recordit.co/Da0PMay2Tp).

This particular example is a simplified version of just a mirror and a sphere on top if it.